# How to open rqt_graph or any other rqt tools from humble docker?

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, docker

I have macOS Ventura, I run ros2 nodes using docker. Currently, I am experiencing some problems for which I need rqt for debugging. Unfortunately, rqt_graph fails to start with the error `could not connect to display`

I run the command `docker run -it --rm --net host -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY  -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw -e QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1 --name ROS2 osrf/ros:humble-desktop-full` to start docker container.

Am I missing something to set in the env?